# Angular Setting Class In Ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a list in an `ng-repeat` , I need to give all `li` elements who are the nth child of their father or more , a certain class (in our `ng-repeat` it means all children who have an index greater than middle) . For example , if the list is 10 items I need to give the 5th,6th...10th `li` children a class .
So if my code is something this -

```
 [ul]
    [li  ng-repeat="friend in friends"]
       {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    [/li]
  [/ul]
```

What is a possible and good way to assign a class to the children from the middle index and above? My conditions are that I shouldn't change the structure of the html . I can add `directives\filters` or add things to controllers.

Comment: simply add somthing like `ng-class="{'yourClass': $index > friends.length / 2}"` on the li.

Comment: that looks like black magic , are you sure it will work?

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure ;) If the logic is subject to change, you could of course extract it from the view and let the controller decide. Eg: `ng-class="someConrollerMethod($index, friends)"`

Comment: @Yoshi, you should create an answer. Perhaps a jsfiddle too.

Comment: i little bit shorter: 

ng-class="{'class-name': $index > $middle}"

Comment: @tschiela `$middle` is a boolean value, so this won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

simply use [`ng-class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) on the repeated element, eg:

```
<li
  ng-repeat="friend in friends"
  ng-class="{special: $index > friends.length / 2 - 1}">

  {{friend.name}}
</li>
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/iFigAYi/1/

---

or extract the logic, like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-class="getClass($index, friends)">
    {{friend.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$scope.getClass = function getClass(idx, list) {
  return {
    special: idx > list.length / 2 - 1
  };
};
```

Comment: I found that "special" had to be in quotes